# Will UK Immigration officers ask for a bank statement if I'm disabled?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork

I have read that in the UK, Ukraine, Germany, Thailand etc., a few hundred in cash, a credit card and a debit card are plenty enough for a US citizen, and that border officers will rarely ask for a bank statement. But I want to visit the UK for 6 months as a tourist and want to know if it's still rare for them to ask for a bank statement from a disabled person.

Comment: They are still going to want to know how you plan on supporting yourself for 6 months without working illegally, and whether your plan is realistic or not (so spending thousands on a credit card when you have no way to repay it will also look very dodgy).  Assume they will ask questions in these areas, and have truthful, appropriate answers for them. Being disabled does not exempt you from having to meet entry criteria.

Comment: @James Smith It’s impossible to say what they’ll ask for, if anything. They shouldn’t single you out for special treatment simply because you are disabled. But you should be prepared to explain your source of funds to Border officials if they ask. Potentially, saying you have a credit and debit card but no bank statements would look  odd, if they do ask. UK advice to visa-free entrants is to bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border. https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism

Comment: You should not get any special treatment for being disabled. Planning to stay 6 months is a different matter. They can ask more questions and require more evidence in that case than they would for the more typical case of a US citizen spending a much a shorter time in the UK as a tourist or on a business trip.

Comment: I don't believe the passport gates are wheelchair accessible, but if you are not confined to a wheelchair then it's likely you'll just go through the gates and not speak to anybody.